# How do I remove all letters until the first digit with sed?

Tags: sed, freebsd

I have the following lines:

```
XYZ2342
ABCD1323
KIL9824
```

And I would like to remove all letters at the beginning, so I would get for the above example:

```
2342
1323
9824
```

I have tried this:

```
echo "ABC12345" |  sed 's/[[:alpha:]]*[[:digit:]]//'
2345
```

But it also removes the first digit, how can I make sed to delete just the letters (note: they are always ASCII).

I am using FreeBSD sed implementation, in case that is relevant.

Comment: `sed 's/[[:alpha:]]*//'` would work for your given sample..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you please try following. We need to substitute everything till first occurrence of digits from starting so we need to use `[^0-9]` regex here, which means from starting substitute everything till first occurrence of digits with NULL here.

```
echo "ABC12345" | sed 's/^[^0-9]*//'
```

Comment: That works thanks, I will accept the answer (I have removed the g because I just want one occurrence)